# Max Length validation for textarea in EXT JS 3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using 3.4 version of ExtJS.

Is there a built in way to stop a user from entering more than the `maxLength` in a `Ext.form.TextArea`?

The built-in validation shows the red outline when it goes over the set `maxLength` but it doesn't stop the user from typing more. I haven't tried much to fix this as it isn't a high priority issue for the users yet, but it would be nice if I didn't have to plug in a validation function to every `textarea` in the app to prevent `entering > maxLength` characters.

I tried the `vtypes` and they don't work for this, though the email `vtype`was a great time saver for email validation.

Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you please post you code. What you did so far ?

Comment: Before you "add it to every textarea", consider an override.

Comment: ExtJS 3.4 don't have enforceMaxLength property for textArea . So you have to add keyup event to handle this type of validation .Check the length of textArea and return if exceeded your Max Length.